# If function with parameters inside Animator

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animator

[image]I tried to make an if statement that goes working when a parameter inside the animator reaches a value. But I dont know how to access those parameters by script. I tried a couple of things (PlayerMovement is a public Animator):

```
if (PlayerMovement.Parameter("PlayerDayDreaming" = 1f))
{
Debug.Log("Switch Scene");
}
```

and

```
if(Playermovement.Parameters.Daydreaming == 1f)
{
Debug.Log("Switch Scene");
}
```

And a couple more look a likes but I just couldnt figure it out. Does somebody know how to do this?

Edit: I added a screenshot

Comment: Hmm. Maybe 'if (PlayerMovement.Parameter("PlayerDayDreaming") == 1f)'?

Comment: Nope doesnt work, says Animator does not contain a definition for Parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unfamiliar if `Animator` has the field `Parameters`. I know it has an array of the parameters as [`paramaters`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator-parameters.html). Generally, when trying to get a specific parameter field, you would use [`GetBool`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.GetBool.html), [`GetInteger`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.GetInteger.html) or any of the corresponding counterparts to your specific parameter field type.

If the field `Parameters` exists in the version of Unity you are using, then you can keep using it. The other mistake in your code as pointed out in the comments is you are currently using the assignment operator (`=`) instead of the comparison operator (`==`) in your if conditional which should always return true as the assignment should succeed. The last issue is you are directly comparing a float, which can have issues due to floating-point precision. I used [`Mathf.Approximately`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html) to fix this.

With using a parameter check based on parameter type and the fixed conditional, the code should looks something like:

```
if(Mathf.Approximately(PlayerMovement.GetFloat("PlayerDayDreaming"), 1f))
{
    Debug.Log("Switch Scene");
}
```

Comment: its not really in the field I suppose, its more that if you open the controller you get into the page with the "animation blocks" then on the left side you have two tabs: Layers and Parameters. I added a picture to show which float I meant

Comment: Oh so you're just asking how your access the fields then and your snippets were more pseudocode? In that case, use the snippet I provided it should do what you'd like. The `PlayerMovement` is the Animator component on your object.

Comment: Okay thank you, it works as it should now. May I ask how Mathf.Approximately works and why its ```, 1f``` instead of ```= 1f``` or ```== 1f```

Comment: Sure! If you click on the hyper link it should have an explanation as to what it is. When dealing with floats, the precision can sometimes lead to inaccuracies meaning 1.0f is not 1.00001f, but it could be stored that way. To account for this, the approximate will run code comparing the absolute value of the two inputs to a delimiter, which is a very small comparison value. Something like `abs(1.0-1.000001) < 0.01`.

Comment: great thanks! I didnt saw that you included a hyper link in the first place also the other part has become clearer